# Horton Sandbox on Azure Tutorial - Can't upload from HDFS into Hive

Tags: azure, hive, hortonworks-sandbox

I am following [this](https://github.com/hortonworks/tutorials/blob/hdp-2.5/tutorials/hortonworks/hello-hdp-an-introduction-to-hadoop/hello-hdp-section-4.md) series of tutorial with my Hortonworks sandbox on Azure.  On Step 2.2.1, it talks about Uploading from HDFS.  However, I only see Uploading from Local
[image]

Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the version of Hadoop I spun up on Azure.  I went ahead and create a script that does the same thing:

````
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE trucks

(driverid INT,
truckid INT,
model STRING,
jun13_miles INT,
jun13_gas INT,
may13_miles INT,
may13_gas INT,
apr13_miles INT,
apr13_gas INT,
mar13_miles INT,
mar13_gas INT,
feb13_miles INT,
feb13_gas INT,
jan13_miles INT,
jan13_gas INT,
dec12_miles INT,
dec12_gas INT,
nov12_miles INT,
nov12_gas INT,
oct12_miles INT,
oct12_gas INT,
sep12_miles INT,
sep12_gas INT,
aug12_miles INT,
aug12_gas INT,
jul12_miles INT,
jul12_gas INT,
jun12_miles INT,
jun12_gas INT,
may12_miles INT,
may12_gas INT,
apr12_miles INT,
apr12_gas INT,
mar12_miles INT,
mar12_gas INT,
feb12_miles INT,
feb12_gas INT,
jan12_miles INT,
jan12_gas INT,
dec11_miles INT,
dec11_gas INT,
nov11_miles INT,
nov11_gas INT,
oct11_miles INT,
oct11_gas INT,
sep11_miles INT,
sep11_gas INT,
aug11_miles INT,
aug11_gas INT,
jul11_miles INT,
jul11_gas INT,
jun11_miles INT,
jun11_gas INT,
may11_miles INT,
may11_gas INT,
apr11_miles INT,
apr11_gas INT,
mar11_miles INT,
mar11_gas INT,
feb11_miles INT,
feb11_gas INT,
jan11_miles INT,
jan11_gas INT,
dec10_miles INT,
dec10_gas INT,
nov10_miles INT,
nov10_gas INT,
oct10_miles INT,
oct10_gas INT,
sep10_miles INT,
sep10_gas INT,
aug10_miles INT,
aug10_gas INT,
jul10_miles INT,
jul10_gas INT,
jun10_miles INT,
jun10_gas INT,
may10_miles INT,
may10_gas INT,
apr10_miles INT,
apr10_gas INT,
mar10_miles INT,
mar10_gas INT,
feb10_miles INT,
feb10_gas INT,
jan10_miles INT,
jan10_gas INT,
dec09_miles INT,
dec09_gas INT,
nov09_miles INT,
nov09_gas INT,
oct09_miles INT,
oct09_gas INT,
sep09_miles INT,
sep09_gas INT,
aug09_miles INT,
aug09_gas INT,
jul09_miles INT,
jul09_gas INT,
jun09_miles INT,
jun09_gas INT,
may09_miles INT,
may09_gas INT,
apr09_miles INT,
apr09_gas INT,
mar09_miles INT,
mar09_gas INT,
feb09_miles INT,
feb09_gas INT,
jan09_miles INT,
jan09_gas INT)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LOCATION '/user/maria_dev/data';```
````